# retain the value of an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I just got stuck. I have 2 view controllers one is "`WatchListViewController`" and 2nd is "`QuotesViewController`" first of all I am pushing from `WatchListViewController` to `QuotesViewController` and my action is written here.

```
-(IBAction)qoutes
{
    QuotesViewController *nextController = [[QuotesViewController alloc] initWithQoutes:symbolForQoutes :exchangeForQoutes :appDelegate.s :code :exchange:exchangeCodeForQoutes];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES]; 
}
```

it works perfectly my `initWithQoutes` method is also working good, then in `ViewDidLoad` method I am sending some request to server via socket and it gives response and reponse is received in my function that is in `WatchListViewController`:

```
void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type,  CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info)
{
    char *buffer = (char *)CFDataGetBytePtr((CFDataRef)data); //getting data from server side in a char type veriable "buffer"
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]; // getting data in a string from  my buffer
    if (strstr(buffer, "QRES") != NULL) { //if this is a qoutes response
        splits = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]; //separating string by "|"
        body = [splits objectAtIndex:1]; // choosing index "1"
        splits = [body componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; // separating by ","
        QuotesViewController *quotesViewController = [[QuotesViewController alloc] init];
        [quotesViewController initWithData:splits];
        return;
    }
}
```

response is received and it goes to the method `initWithData` with a parameter array "splits" i receive this array in my initWithData and assign it to my other array (`generalArray`) now general array is assigned to my `tableView` but before it `reloadData` of tableView its control goes back to `receiveData` and return and come back again to my `QuotesViewController` and reload table view but at that time my array (`generalArray`) lost its value & values are not loaded in table view.
plz plz help me i got stuck here.

code of method initWithData:

```
-(void)initWithData:(NSArray *)_general
{ 
general = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //initializing array that can be accessed out of the class 
for (int i=0; i< [_general count]; i++) { 
[general addObject:[_general objectAtIndex:i]]; } 
NSLog(@"%@", general); [self generalValues]; 
} 
-(void)generalValues{ 

[generalTableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: can u be clear with the last statement i lost the link when i was reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `QuotesViewController` instance here in your C function as –

```
[quotesViewController initWithData:splits];
```

You are not storing a reference to this controller. It is highly likely that this instance of `QuotesViewController` has the proper values in `generalArray`. But since you are not storing it for later use, a reference is lost and a memory leak is created.

Now, if you go on to create another instance of `QuotesViewController`, it will not have earlier `generalArray` data as it is a new instance. Since I do not understand the flow of your program, I find it hard to suggest a proper way to go forward but it would be correct to save either the reference in the function or the array itself. If you save the reference, you can simply push it into the navigation controller of if you save the array, you can pass it in the init method.

**EDIT**

Since you are talking of affecting the same controller, you will need to pass the reference to the function.

```
void receiveData(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type,  CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info, QuotesViewController *controller)
{
    char *buffer = (char *)CFDataGetBytePtr((CFDataRef)data); //getting data from server side in a char type veriable "buffer"
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]; // getting data in a string from  my buffer
    if (strstr(buffer, "QRES") != NULL) { //if this is a qoutes response
        splits = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]; //separating string by "|"
        body = [splits objectAtIndex:1]; // choosing index "1"
        splits = [body componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; // separating by ","
        [controller initWithData:splits];
        return;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this should do it.

Comment: you are too right but this response is coming after after pushing. infect this response is of a request that is generated from "ViewDidLoad".

Comment: So you have pushed a `QuotesViewController` instance to the front and then trigger a request that should update the `general` array in the same instance right?

Answer (score 0):

You should study memory management in Objective-C. The array you create with `componentsSeparatedByString` is autoreleased by that method. So when you pass it into the `initWithData` method of QuotesViewController, you need to retain it in that method with something like

```
generalArray = [splits retain];
```

Post your `initWithData` code if you're not sure what to do.

Comment: thanx for reply here is the code 
-(void)initWithData:(NSArray *)_general{
 general = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //initializing array that can be accessed out of the class
 for (int i=0; i< [_general count]; i++) {
  
  [general addObject:[_general objectAtIndex:i]];
  
  
 }
 NSLog(@"%@", general);
 [self generalValues];
}
-(void)generalValues{
 [generalTableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Can you post your code as an edit to your question? It's hard to read it all bunched up in a comment like that.

Comment: @Mashhadi: You can avoid the loop that copies `_general` to `general` with the line: `general = [_general mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
QuotesViewController *quotesViewController = [[QuotesViewController alloc] init];
[quotesViewController initWithData:splits];
```

you are initializing `quotesViewController` twice. The second time you initialize it, you are not storing the return value, so your reference is lost. Instead, you should write

```
QuotesViewController *quotesViewController = [[QuotesViewController alloc] initWithData:splits];
```

Try that and see if it helps.